# How to pass filter data to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am designing a UI where I have list of applications for a project. Along with that I have functionality of filtering applications on basis of application type.
There is a button on UI called **select ALL**. If I apply filter on applications by `type of application` it returns me filtered data.
So how will I know which all applications are returned so that select All will select only filtered applications in place of all applications for that project.

e.g suppose there is a Test project and for which I have APP1, App2, App3, App4 and App5. After applying filter it returns App1, App3, App4 once I click **select All** button it should select only App1, App3, App4 not App2 and App5.

for filtering the application I have defined `.filter` in my module and the select All button calls a method selectAllApp() inside my controller. 
Is there any way to share the filtered Applications with controller?

Comment: can your put code or codepen?

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh for showing interest, unfortunately I can not post my code, but I have solved my problem mentioned as below.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by dependency injection of $filter in my controller.
So if my filter name id appFilter, I call the filter operation `$filter('appFilter')(arg)`
in my selectAll() method of controller. After the filter call I apply select operation only on returned app by filter.